# Error: Unknown provider / Accessing controller in factory

Tags: angularjs

How can I access AuthenticationCtrl in the following piece of code?

Code:

```
app.factory( 'AuthenticationInterceptor', function( $q, $injector ) 
{
    return {
        response: function (response) 
        {
            // Bypass the success.
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (response) 
        {   
            // Sign out if the user is no longer authorized.
            if (response.status == 401) 
            {
                console.log("test 1"); // shows up in console
                var AuthenticationCtrl = $injector.get( 'AuthenticationCtrl' );
                console.log("test 2"); // does not show up in console
                AuthenticationCtrl.signOut();
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

Error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: AuthenticationCtrlProvider <- AuthenticationCtrl
at Error (native)
at file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js:2765:46
at Object.getService [as get] (file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js:2891:39)
at file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js:2770:45
at Object.getService [as get] (file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js:2891:39)
at responseError (file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/scripts/common/interceptor/AuthenticationInterceptor.js:17:40)
at wrappedErrback (file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js:7518:57)
at wrappedErrback (file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js:7518:57)
at file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js:7630:53
at Object.Scope.$eval (file:///C:/node/corsnection/client/app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js:8926:28)
```

PS: The code is from https://github.com/pablodenadai/Corsnection - I am  trying to get it working for me to learn about user authentication with node and angular.

Comment: Is `AuthenticationCtrl` in a separate file? If so, is that file being loaded? Check your developer tools (network tab in chrome) to make sure it gets loaded. If not, you might be missing a script tag

Comment: I think it's a bad practice to call controller's method from service, it should be the other way

Comment: You should probably make an AuthenticationService which can be called from here and from your AuthenticationController

Comment: For interceptors AngularJS provides decorators http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/$provide#decorator

Answer (score 0):

`$injector.get()` can be used to get services and services only. Controllers are instantiated through the `$ControllerProvider`, as they need special treatment. They need a scope, e.g.

Moreover controllers are not singletons, so you don't get **the** `AuthenticationCtrl`, but rather **a** `AuthenticationCtrl`.

Even if you got your controller (which is possible with some effort), it would be completely useless in your case, since `AuthenticationCtrl` has no methods (in the code from github). Which means you can't call `AuthenticationCtrl.signOut()`, because `signOut()` is defined in the scope of the view.

As it has been pointed out by others you could use a service for this task. Or you fire an event that the controller listens to.